# can you set permissions with HooKan Permissions Manager

Tags: permissions

can you set permissions with HooKan Permissions Manager, or does it just display them? I see this plugin is for setting permissions and I didn't know if I needed to get both, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-permissions

Answer (score 2):

You can set permissions with HooKan. The HooKan CP will display permission statuses as you set/unset them. The interface is ajax, so you see status as you make changes.